# Getting the List values from Form Controls

Tags: excel, vba

I have a dropdown Form Control in my Excel sheet. Its input range is a named range, which contains another named ranges. I wanted after change user be redirected to selected name range. I have difficulties with Directly getting Selected name ranges from dropdown control. All I get is list value of the dronwdown control. I did a workaround thought and select the appropriate cell from the main Named range, but I am wondering there should be a way to directly get the string value of selected item. Here is my code and the one I already tried.

> ** this works:

```
Sub GotoNames()
Dim rng As Range, T As Range
    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Panel").Range("NamedRng")
    On Error GoTo errr
Retry:
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").DropDowns(1)
       Set T = rng(.Value)
       Application.Goto T.Value2
    End With
    Exit Sub
errr:
    If T.Worksheet.Visible = xlSheetHidden Then
        T.Worksheet.Visible = xlSheetVisible
        resume Retry
    End If
End Sub
```

But I wanted:

```
Sub GotoNames()
'On Error Resume Next
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").DropDowns(1)
        Application.Goto .ControlFormat.List(.ControlFormat.ListIndex) 'OR
        Application.Goto .ListFillRange(.value)
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: `GoTo Retry` isn't resetting the error state, so a second error would bubble up the call stack and crash the program. Needs to be `Resume Retry`

Comment: Good catch, Noted Thanks.

Comment: Does it have to be a "form control"? Looks like what you want is ActiveX controls.

Comment: No It is form control, I had Activex control. By Activex control it is pretty simple as I can get the text value of the combo box. I prefer to use form control. The first code is working fine. I just was looking a more direct way if available.